# How to make keyboard open and textFormField hover over keyboard while opening Dart Flutter showModalBottomSheet?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an application like this:

[image]

When I press the `floatActionButton` below, this is what happens:

[image]

When I come to this screen, I want the keyboard to open automatically.

---

When I press the textFormField myself, a screen like this happens:

[image]

The keyboard is getting ahead of the textFormField. How do I prevent this?

So, when showModalBottomSheet is opened, I want both the keyboard to open automatically and the keyboard not to get in front of the textFormField. How can I do that?

I want to do like this:

[image]

---

Codes:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
    ),
  ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return Container(
      height: 125,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Add new task',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your Container with another Container and give

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
),
```

and also give `isScrollControlled: true` in `showModalBottomSheet()`

Like In your example,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .viewInsets
                      .bottom,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 125,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Add new task',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),

                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. Your code worked exactly as I wanted. I also added a `Divider` under this `textFormField`. But for some reason it goes right under the field. I want it to be below the full `textFormField`. How can I do that? Thanks.

View: https://imgur.com/a/K9uV34X
Code: https://codepen.io/speedev/pen/popyJxz

Comment: For putting divider below the textFormField you don't need to use `Divider` you can use the `border` property inside the `TextFormField` and give `UnderlineInputBorder` and give it borderSide property. Now underline shows exactly below the TextFormField. For border and focusedBorder you can use the different color if you want.